# Not able to connect to remote EC2-hbase cluster from EMR hive cluster

Tags: amazon-ec2, hbase, hive, apache-zookeeper, amazon-emr

Before i ask my question let me first explain the scenario. I had setup the `hbase` cluster on `ec2` with 3 instances:

```
i-xxxxxxx-- master, zookeeper1, regionserver1
i-xxxxxxx-- slave1, zookeeper2, regionserver2
i-xxxxxxx-- slave2, zookeeper3, regionserver3.
```

Which was working perfectly fine. Now, I was trying to connect to master of this cluster with the remote EMR instance with hive installed.
So, I followed this link of amazon aws documentation :

```
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-hbase-access-hive.html
```

Which says before you create some table. Let hive knows the public-DNS of remote hbase master. 
set hbase.zookeeper.quorum=public-DNS-name;
 I did exactly which has been mentioned. But, I was not able to connect to the master. I tried create one table using the following script :

```
CREATE TABLE hauto(cookie string, timespent string, pageviews string, visit string, logdate string) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = "m:timespent, m:pageviews, m:visit, m:logdate")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "hauto");
```

So, it gave this error :

```
FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Retried 10 times
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.getHBaseAdmin(HBaseStorageHandler.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.preCreateTable(HBaseStorageHandler.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:460)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:74)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.createTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:600)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:3791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:945)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:819)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:674)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:187)
)
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

FYI, `EMR` hive installed instance and EC2 `Hbase-cluster` are in same security group. I am
able to telnet to 2181, 60000, 60010, 60020 ports from EMR to EC2 as well as EC2 to EMR. 
And in that group i have allowed the tcp, udp and ICMP connections on all ports within the group.

My /etc/hosts file  of master look like this:

```
XXXXXXXXXXX master localhost
XXXXXXXXXXX zkserver1 rgserver1 
XXXXXXXXXXX zkserver2 rgserver2
XXXXXXXXXXX zkserver3 rgserver3
```

I am using `hadoop 1.0.1`,  `hbase 0.94.11`, `hive 0.11.0` and `zookeeper-3.4.3`. And zookeeper is manager externally.

Also, after that i tried other way around. This time i tried to connect from hive CLI installed on EC2 Hbase cluster to EMR Hbase. Now, i was able to create the same table on EMR hbase.

**Updated Question:**

It seems like this is an issue with amazon ec2. I am providing you the snapshot of those issues also the link :

```
http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#trouble.log.gc
```

[image]

Comment: Did you enable all the necessary ports in the security group (firewall) ?

Comment: Yes, I have kept the my Ec2 hbase cluster on the same security group in which EMR by default spin the Hadoop-hive instances. And in that group i have allowed the tcp connections on all ports within the group.

Comment: You should allow the udp too

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mentioned earlier. But, i also allowed the ICMP and UDP connection on all ports for that security group.

Comment: Try to telnet on that port.

Comment: I know this is not answer to your question but you should dedicated instances for ZK! ie only ZK services should be running on those instances!